# Will plastic damage RPi?

Tags: pi-4

This my sound stupid but will putting a Raspberry Pi 4b damage it? Will it melt the plastic and damge the Raspberry Pi? Or will the plastic be gooey and sticky and stick to the Pi?

I just relocated my Pi onto a desk which has a plastic cover. Will it damage the Pi?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it won't. First the melting point of plastic isn't that low and second your pi produces the most heat at the CPU and not at the bottom.